# List of Tuples switching order randomly

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, pandas, tuples

So when constructing a list of tuples, the order within some of the tuples seems to mix up. The content within `each_file[2]` will be before the content `each_file[1]` randomly.

Example output from printing filelist:

```
[{ef1, ef2}, {ef1, ef2} {ef2, ef1}, {ef1, ef2} ....]
```

Information about about the code below:
projectDict is a list of pandas.dataframe objects

```
filelist = []
for each_dict in projectDict:
    currentDataFrame = projectDict[each_dict]

    for each_file in currentDataFrame.itertuples(): 
        important_terms = { each_file[1], 
                            each_file[2]}
        filelist.append(important_terms)
```

**Is this a result of using itertuples, or is there another glaring error within my code?** I used iterrows and had the same issue. I also have verified that the data is not structured in the way of the output.

Comment: `important_items` is a set, sets are unordered.

Comment: Those are **not** tuples, but **sets** and the order of a **set is undetermined**.

Comment: Thanks so much, that was pretty dumb error!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You write:

```
important_terms = {each_file[1],each_file[2]}
#                 ^     curly brackets      ^
```

Now the syntax **`{a,b,...,z}` is a `set`**. In a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset), an **element occurs at most once** and the **order is undetermined**. Like is written in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset):

> A `set` object is an **unordered collection** of **distinct** hashable
>   objects. Common uses include membership testing, removing duplicates
>   from a sequence, and computing mathematical operations such as
>   intersection, union, difference, and symmetric difference.

The **syntax for a [`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range) is `(a,b,...,z)`**. So you should change the line to:

```
important_terms = (each_file[1],each_file[2])
#                 ^     round brackets      ^
```

Or - as [@Matthias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42673269/list-of-tuples-switching-order-randomly/42673336?noredirect=1#comment72472831_42673336) says - you can even omit the rounded brackets and only use the comma:

```
important_terms = each_file[1],each_file[2]
#                 ^       no brackets     ^
```

Nevertheless, you can here **use slicing**, since `each_file` is already a tuple:

```
important_terms = each_file[1:3]
```

Here you slice from index `1` (inclusive) to index `3` (exclusive).

Finally you can use *list comprehension* to turn your *entire program* into a *one liner*:

```
filelist = [each_file[1:3] for each_dict in projectDict
                           for each_file in projectDict[each_dict].itertuples()]
```

or even more elegantly:

```
filelist = [each_file[1:3] for each_dict in projectDict.values()
                           for each_file in each_dict.itertuples()]
```

Comment: You don't even need the round brackets. `important_terms = each_file[1], each_file[2]` is enough, but the parentheses can be added as a visual help.

Comment: @Matthias: agreed. Nevertheless I think it can be useful. But I will add a note to the answer.